# Asian characters appear in iOS text manipulation options inside Cordova application

Tags: ios, cordova

In our Cordova 3.5.0 application run on iOS 7.0.2, we face the following strange behaviour:

When we select text inside the app, iOS text manipulation options are shown (where should be Select, Select All, Paste, or other word suggestions in English). However instead of English words, we got the options written with Asian characters (unfortunately I don't know the actual language).

If I try it in other applications (e.g Safari, Notes), it works fine. If I try it on later iOS versions, it also works fine.

What I have already tried are:

- Re-installed application
- Added new Asian languages inside iOS, and changed back to English
- Added / deleted  other keyboards
- Reset keyboard dictionary

Sadly, none of that solved the problem.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause that, or how to fix this?

[image: Text manipulation issue]

Comment: Post some screenshots. Also i m suggesting you to upgrade cordova as you are using very old cordova version

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added an image as you requested. Upgrading Cordova is not an option for me, because of other reasons.

Comment: Should be device language setting issue. With cordova 3.x version you cant get it certified in iOS App Store for sure